# How can I add an image to each div in the results of a Google Places API call?

Tags: javascript, html, google-places-api

I'm trying to embed google reviews into a website. I'm trying to add this image into each review. Currently it generates 4 reviews but it doesn't add the image into each one and instead it just places it at the bottom of the page.

Also the height of each review doesn't seem to adapt to the content of each review and instead stays fixed even though I set the height to auto.

```css
#map-plug {
  display: none;
}

#google-reviews {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 18px;
  height: auto;
}

.review-item {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 8px solid #D1D9DC;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px flex: 1 1 20%;
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

@media ( max-width:1200px) {
  .review-item {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
  }
}

@media ( max-width:200px) {
  .review-item {
    flex: 1 1 90%;
  }
}

.review-meta,
.review-stars {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 115%;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-author {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-date {
  opacity: .8;
  display: block;
}

.review-text {
  line-height: 1.55;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 32em;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-stars ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.review-stars ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin-right: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.review-stars ul li i {
  color: #FBBC04;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-style: normal;
}

.review-stars ul li i.inactive {
  color: #c6c6c6;
}

.star:after {
  content: "\2605";
}

img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="google-reviews"></div>

<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/91e6ab_532fade046284b2cab41a13a4ba3fb8e~mv2.webp" class="logo">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/stevenmonson/googleReviews@6e8f0d794393ec657dab69eb1421f3a60add23ef/google-places.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=APIKEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places">
</script>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
      placeId: 'PlaceID',
      render: ['reviews'],
      min_rating: 5,
      max_rows: 4
    });
  });
</script>
```

Output HTML:

```css
.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,
.gm-style .gm-style-cc button,
.gm-style .gm-style-cc span,
.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div {
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,
.gm-style .gm-style-cc button,
.gm-style .gm-style-cc span {
  outline-offset: 3px
}

#map-plug {
  display: none;
}

#google-reviews {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));*/
  gap: 18px;
  height: auto;
}

.review-item {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 8px solid #D1D9DC;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px flex: 1 1 20%;
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

@media ( max-width:1200px) {
  .review-item {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
  }
}

@media ( max-width:200px) {
  .review-item {
    flex: 1 1 90%;
  }
}

.review-meta,
.review-stars {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 115%;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-author {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-date {
  opacity: .8;
  display: block;
}

.review-text {
  line-height: 1.55;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 32em;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-stars ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.review-stars ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin-right: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.review-stars ul li i {
  color: #FBBC04;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-style: normal;
}

.review-stars ul li i.inactive {
  color: #c6c6c6;
}

.star:after {
  content: "\2605";
}

img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body contenteditable="false">
  <div id="google-reviews">
    <div id="map-plug">
      <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <div style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="review-item">
      <div class="review-meta"><span class="review-author">Tuan H</span><span class="review-sep">, </span><span class="review-date">May 30, 2023</span></div>
      
      <div class="review-stars">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <p class="review-text">Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-item">
      <div class="review-meta"><span class="review-author">Asha Wadhwa</span><span class="review-sep">, </span><span class="review-date">May 27, 2023</span></div>
      
      <div class="review-stars">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <p class="review-text">Text</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="review-item">
      <div class="review-meta"><span class="review-author">Tash N</span><span class="review-sep">, </span><span class="review-date">May 23, 2023</span></div>
      <div class="review-stars">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <p class="review-text">Text</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="review-item">
      <div class="review-meta"><span class="review-author">Siobhan Brennan</span><span class="review-sep">, </span><span class="review-date">May 22, 2023</span></div>
      <div class="review-stars">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <p class="review-text">Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/91e6ab_532fade046284b2cab41a13a4ba3fb8e~mv2.webp" class="logo">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: By the way, it looks like you're using a rather [old jQuery library](https://www.launch2success.com/guide/display-google-reviews-website-2017). If so, consider that it seems unsupported and may quit working at any time. It also doesn't have great documentation, or, apparently, support for a callback function.

Comment: ```.review-item {width: 200px; flex: 1 1 20%;}``` Should be separated with a semicolon

Answer (score 0):

After the results of the API call are returned, append a clone of an element to each box. The clone spares you from having to recreate the image element each time.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  /* 
  $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
    placeId: 'PlaceID',
    render: ['reviews'],
    min_rating: 5,
    max_rows: 4
  });
  */

  // in a callback on the function above... 
  const imageEl = $('<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/91e6ab_532fade046284b2cab41a13a4ba3fb8e~mv2.webp" class="logo">');

  $('.review-item').each(function() {
    $(this).append(imageEl.clone());
  });
});
```

```css
.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,
.gm-style .gm-style-cc button,
.gm-style .gm-style-cc span,
.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div {
  font-size: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,
.gm-style .gm-style-cc button,
.gm-style .gm-style-cc span {
  outline-offset: 3px
}

#map-plug {
  display: none;
}

#google-reviews {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 18px;
  height: auto;
}

.review-item {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 8px solid #D1D9DC;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

@media ( max-width:1200px) {
  .review-item {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
  }
}

@media ( max-width:200px) {
  .review-item {
    flex: 1 1 90%;
  }
}

.review-meta,
.review-stars {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 115%;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-author {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-date {
  opacity: .8;
  display: block;
}

.review-text {
  line-height: 1.55;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 32em;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Inter", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.review-stars ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.review-stars ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none !important;
  margin-right: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.review-stars ul li i {
  color: #FBBC04;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-style: normal;
}

.review-stars ul li i.inactive {
  color: #c6c6c6;
}

.star:after {
  content: "\2605";
}

img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body contenteditable="false">
  <div id="google-reviews">
    <div id="map-plug">
      <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <div style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="review-item">
      <div class="review-meta"><span class="review-author">Tuan H</span><span class="review-sep">, </span><span class="review-date">May 30, 2023</span></div>

      <div class="review-stars">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <p class="review-text">I came to Ricky a few years ago to resolve some tax issues, and he was able to come up with a plan to help achieve this. Since then I have been going to Ricky every year for my taxes. Ricky is very professional and does a great job with communicating.
        He is very knowledgeable and has always been really helpful with answering any questions and concerns I have. Thanks Ricky!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-item">
      <div class="review-meta"><span class="review-author">Asha Wadhwa</span><span class="review-sep">, </span><span class="review-date">May 27, 2023</span></div>

      <div class="review-stars">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <p class="review-text">Mr Ricky Chawla has been doing my taxes for many years and I have always found him to be highly professional, knowledgeable and courteous. He takes a comprehensive approach to preparing personal taxes, always looking to maximize benefits for his
        clients. As an example, I asked him to prepare returns for my elderly parents whose health was deteriorating. He recognized that we should have been claiming the Disability Tax Credit - not only did he carry the application process through from
        beginning to end on their behalf with CRA but he also went back to apply the tax credit to past years too. He is a highly recommended accountant.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="review-item">
      <div class="review-meta"><span class="review-author">Tash N</span><span class="review-sep">, </span><span class="review-date">May 23, 2023</span></div>
      <div class="review-stars">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <p class="review-text">Ricky's patience, level of knowledge and professionalism have truly impressed me. His expertise in taxation and financial planning is unmatched, and he consistently identifies opportunities for growth and cost-saving measures. Ricky's integrity
        and ethical standards foster a deep sense of trust, and his punctuality and attention to detail demonstrate remarkable professionalism. I highly recommend Ricky for anyone seeking consultation.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="review-item">
      <div class="review-meta"><span class="review-author">Siobhan Brennan</span><span class="review-sep">, </span><span class="review-date">May 22, 2023</span></div>
      <div class="review-stars">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <p class="review-text">Ricky and his team are fantastic. As a newcomer to Canada as well as a small business owner I required professional help when filing my taxes as I didn’t want to make any mistakes. Ricky has always been very patient with me when it comes to tax
        season, ensuring that I have all the relevant documentation submitted from the start to make sure the process runs smoothly. He always answers my questions professionally and in a manner I can comprehend. I highly recommend their services especially
        if you (like me) prefer a stress free tax season each year. Thank you Ricky!</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I added in the javascript code you wrote but now the picture entirely disappears. I swapped the '.review-item' with "#google-reivews" to test and it seems to appear then, so the issue is possibly the element that's passed as a parameter?

Comment: The picture isn't supposed to be in your markup in the first place, so I'm not sure why it would disappear. I'm also unclear why you'd replace a series of elements with a single element.

Comment: The picture disappears entirely. It doesn't appear in the review.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. There's no image _to_ disappear until my function places one.

Comment: The image doesn't appear in the review when I add lines 12-16 from your javascript code.

Comment: Well, the only reason that wouldn't happen is if the selector passed to the `each()` function doesn't exist at the time it runs. Have you done any debugging in your browser's dev tools? It's easy to set a breakpoint and see what's there. I can't help more in the blind. Good luck.